# MS EWS 2.0 search filter with Both and and or

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

Please would some help me the syntax for the below in VB.net. I'm using MS EWS 2.0

```
SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, True) or 
( New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, False) and 
  New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.lastmodifieldtime >= "2021-10-08 16:30") )
```

I can do the each part of the search separately but not sure how to combine them.

Thank you

Comment: Probably need a bit more context here, maybe update your question please.  What is the point of your first 2 contions?  Kind if reads to me like "IF True OR False"

Comment: I'm try to search for all unread emails and all read email that where read after a date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You should have nested searchfilters using two SearchFilterCollection object eg

```
SearchFilterCollection1 
-OR
--(any # of SearchFilters)
--SearchFilterCollection2 
---AND
----(any # of SearchFilters)
```

Comment: How would I add both condition to the FindItems(nunSearchFilterC, nunView) statement.

Comment: the second SearchFilterCollection is nested inside the first so you only ever adding one SearchFilter object.

Comment: Hi Glen, Sorry for the late response. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.